# Struts 2 Annotated Action finding

Tags: eclipse, jsp, struts2

I have the following problem.
I am working on a new Stuts2 project which is half way done.
The action classes are annotated, and not XML configured. My problem is: it is very difficult to find the class an action is mapped to.

Is there any way to jump to the class where the action is executed?

Example:
in the JSP i have following code:

```
<s:url var="ajax" value="/ajax1.action" />
```

How can I very quickly find the action class this action is mapped to.
My project has more than 500 classes.
I am using Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: use `search` function from `IDE` or `file system`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use a Struts 2 plugin that tracks annotations (e.g., IntelliJ, MyEclipse) you'll need to search.

IMO this problem is a non-issue if you have named your actions in a logical, consistent fashion: finding functionality should be easy even without IDE support. This takes some time and thought during the development process, but pays dividends in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only option is to search for it. You can do a global search in Eclipse `Ctrl+H` -> `File Search`.